# C++ and VS: Wrong Formatting after multiple copies of else if block

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I noticed a strange behaviour of vs community when copying an else if block with a switch statement in it multiple times.

There is a comment below which claims that it is not reproducible, so if you can reproduce this problem a comment on this would be nice. If nobody can reproduce this behaviour an answer would be great which explains what I am doing wrong.

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2019
- Windows 10

The Problem:

You copy an else if block with a switch statement in it.
If you paste and change it up to 4 times the formatting works fine when you continue coding.

```
MyClass::MyMethod()
{
  ...

  if(cond0)
  {
    ...
  }
  else if(cond1) //that block was copied
  {
    ...
  }
  else if(cond2) //that block was pasted and changed
  {
    ...
  }

  .
  .
  .
  else if(cond5) //the last block which was pasted and changed
  {
    ...
  }
  else  //formatting continues to work fine
  {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

[image]

but if you paste the else-if block one more time this happens

```
MyClass::MyMethod()
{
  ...

  if(cond0)
  {
    ...
  }
  else if(cond1) //that block was copied
  {
    ...
  }
  else if(cond2) //that block was pasted and changed
  {
    ...
  }

  .
  .
  .

  else if(cond6) //the last block which was pasted and changed
  {  
    ...
  }
  else 
  {//here starts the problem: everything after this line too much left
  ...  
}

...

}
```

[image]

Has Someone an idea how to avoid this?

Comment: You should provide a screenshot of your VS code along with the code so that the indentation is clearly visible.

Comment: Which version of visual studio did you use? I tested 2019 and 2020 and did not encounter the problem you said.

Comment: @Yujian Yao - MSFT  Visual Studio 2019  I tested it opening Visual Studio from the Unreal4 Editor and creating  a Project in Visual Studio directly and in both cases this problem appeared. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: I suggest you try to reset [settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings).